# graphics in python to make a task manger

Tags: python, graphics

I am designing a task manager for a month using graphics in python. I have created the calendar for the month of July. I would like  to display the tasks for a given date, add new tasks, remove/delete tasks and save the changes to a file.

The maximum number of to do tasks for any day is 5. Initially, the list of tasks are read from a file. Each row in the file contains the date followed by a list of semi-colon separated tasks for that date. The following shows an example file:

1; Go to class;Book Train Ticket

2; Call Home

3; Wash the Clothes

7; Submit the Assignment Online

8; Give Assignment Demo;Prepare for Major

10; Take the Exam

11; Go Home

To the right of calendar, there is a textbox to enter a new task to the list of to-do tasks for the date currently being displayed. After entering the new task in the textbox, I  need to click on the ’ok’ button to add it to the list. As soon as the ’ok’ button is pressed, the list of tasks being displayed should be refreshed to reflect the addition of the new task. The textbox should be cleared after the changes have been incorporated into the task list. Here's my code:

```
from graphics import *
win =GraphWin("Task Manager",800,800)

head = Text(Point(130,15),"July2014")
head.setSize(16)
head.draw(win)


add = Text(Point(440,28),"Add Task :")
add.setSize(17)
add.draw(win)

adde = Entry(Point(560,28),20)
adde.draw(win)

rem  = Text(Point(440,78),"Remove Task:")
rem.setSize(17)
rem.draw(win)

reme = Entry(Point(570,78),20)
reme.draw(win)

addr = Rectangle(Point(680,15),Point(640,45))
addr.setFill("yellow")
addr.draw(win)

okt = Text(Point(660,30),"ok")
okt.setSize(16)
okt.draw(win)


remr = Rectangle(Point(690,60),Point(650,90))
remr.setFill("green")
remr.draw(win)

okt = Text(Point(670,75),"ok")
okt.setSize(16)
okt.draw(win)


savr =Rectangle(Point(440,120),Point(540,150))
savr.setFill("orange")
savr.draw(win)

savt = Text(Point(490,135),"Save to file")
savt.setSize(15)
savt.draw(win)

exir = Rectangle(Point(590,120),Point(650,150))
exir.setFill("red")
exir.draw(win)

exis = Text(Point(620,135),"exit")
exis.setSize(15)
exis.draw(win)

def isInside(p,rect):
    rectP1 = rect.getP1();
    rectP2 = rect.getP2();
    if(p.getX() >= rectP1.getX() and p.getX() <= rectP2.getX() and 
       p.getY() >= rectP1.getY() and p.getY() <= rectP2.getY()):
         return True;
    else:
         return False;

dtext = Text(Point(180,350),"no date selected yet")
dtext.setSize(16)
dtext.draw(win)

def rect(a):
    squ = Rectangle(Point(20+((a-1)%7)*40,70+(((a-1)//7)-1)*30),Point(20+(((a-      1)%7)+1)*40,70+((a-1)//7)*30))
    return squ
for i in range(1,43):
    rect(i).draw(win)

l =['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat']
def elem(a):
    p = Point(40+((a-1)%7)*40,85+(((a-1)//7)-1)*30)
    sti = Text(p,l[a-1])
    sti.setSize(15)
    return sti
for i in range(1,8):
    elem(i).draw(win)

def num(a):
    p = Point(40+((a-1)%7)*40,85+(((a-1)//7)-1)*30)
    b = Text(p,a-9)
    return b
for j in range(10,41):
    num(j).draw(win)

id = Text(Point(50,400),"id")
id.setSize(17)
id.draw(win)

task = Text(Point(200,400),"task")
task.setSize(17)
task.draw(win)
while 9 < a< 41:
  inputP = win.getMouse()
  if isInside(inputP,rect(a)):
    dtext.setText("tasks on July"+rect(a).getText()+"are")
  else:
     dtext.setText("wrong")




win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

Comment: i want to ask how can i call each rectangle containing a particular date and add tasks using the file which stores the tasks and date.

Comment: One good way to do it is to store the calendar data somewhere other than in the rectangles. For example you can have a dictionary for which the key is a date and the value is a list of tasks for that date. It is from this dict that you will populate your rectangles, and every time the something is updated in the dict you can draw the rectangles afresh, or, you can have another dict that stores a date and its corresponding rectangle as key,val respectively (the first one is the simplest).